# SQL Management Studio show network drives

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image]I'm using Microsoft SQL Management Studio to import a data set into a database. I need to be able to point all log files into a network drive, but i cannot see any network drives when i browser via SQL Management Studio. Is there a way to enable network drives view via SQL Management. Many Thanks

Comment: You know there's a good reason that you can't put log files on a network drive. You're more likely to not be able to access a network drive and when that happens, your database will stop.

Answer (score 0):

It is not depend by ssms. It is because your DB Engine is runing as "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER", so yours network drives must be maped for this user if you want to use it. On other hand you can use full network location like "\\MyServer\MyResource\MyBackup.bak".

Comment: The network drive is mapped. When i try to select a path it only shows the c: drive, and need to be able to see network drives mapped.

Comment: But is it maped for your user or DB Engine user?

Comment: There is some [trick](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3499/make-network-path-visible-for-sql-server-backup-and-restore-in-ssms/) to map drive stright from sql script.

Comment: You can see also threads on [dba stack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=sql+server+maped+drive)

Comment: It's mapped to the user's account.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of my suggestion to fix the problem ... but I say, and I hope it helps.

You will use the **xp_cmdshell** command. Before that, you need to make sure that the xp_cmdshell command is enabled in your SQL instance, as it is disabled by default. Use the **`sp_configure`** command to enable it as shown below:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Now define that share drive for SQL with the xp_cmdshell command as follows:

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use H: \\RemoteServerName\ShareName'
```

It should now be mapped. In order to verify the new drive, you can use the below command that will show you all files in that newly mapped drive:

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'Dir H:'
```

Let’s try to use SQL Server Management Studio again to browse the path.  As we can see below, we can now see the H: drive:

[image]
Now that he drive is visible, you can proceed normally with the restore process and etc.

Comment: ref : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3499/make-network-path-visible-for-sql-server-backup-and-restore-in-ssms/

Comment: I did follow the above instruction but i still cannot see the network drive.

Comment: @AA2018-2020 what is you ssms version... and what to do exactly, i used this method, it's worked.

Comment: @AA2018-2020 i used this method for Back Up in maintenance plan SSMS

Comment: I'm using SSMS V18.4. Basically, i am trying to create a new database and part of the set up is to change the path into a network drive. I have uploaded a picture to show the path i am trying to change.

Comment: @AA2018-2020 ... Oh, its not good idea. you try to add MDF and LDF file to network. I don't think it's possible. Technically there are a lot of drawbacks, and I wouldn't recommend it. 1- Never place your original LDF and MDF file away from your SQL engine installation. (Even if it is possible, you will have a slowdown, definitely) 2- You can make an hourly backup and place it on another network and system.

Comment: @AA2018-2020 i try to help you, and edit your question for attract other person (like network programmers ) to help you.  you can find me here and my linkedin.

Comment: I have a limited HD size on the VM running SQL, that's why i am trying to make use of network drive.

Comment: @AA2018-2020 I don't think you can do that. This trick lets you do things like transferring backups. I only do this for backups, and I really didn't expect to be able to put the file off your disk. But another solution is to install an engine sql on another OS on the network (like remotely connect). And then connect to **ssms** via **ip address** from vm. for manage Database...The features that **Engine has in SQL** affect LDF and MDF management over storage, so there should be sql -engine wherever they are.